# Função autorizando ou não submit do form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando executar uma função no submit do formulário, ela funciona corretamente, porém se retornar `true` eu preciso que o formulário não seja enviado.
Está sendo feito desta forma:

```
    $('#FornecedorNovo').submit(function (e) {
    var url = "/Fornecedor/VerificaInscricao";
    var Insc = $("#InscricaoEstadual").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { insc: Insc },
        datatype: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.resultado == true) {
                alert('Já existe esta inscrição estadual cadastrada para outro fornecedor.');
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    })

});
```

Porém mesmo assim o formulário é enviado.

Comment: Coloca um `return false;`

Comment: Você poderia fazer com que a requisição ajax fosse síncrona, mas o ideal seria deixar o formulário ser enviado e fazer esta validação no servidor.

Comment: O evento é assíncrono, então a função irá finalizar antes de você obter a resposta via AJAX. Assim, o `e.preventDefault()` nunca será executado, deixando o formulário ser submetido normalmente. Mas a pergunta é: e se retornar falso, o que deve acontecer?

Comment: Se retornar false o formulário deve ser enviado, ele está enviando de qualquer forma. Em uma outra função que faço no submit utilizo o `e.preventDefault()` e funciona.

Comment: @PedroAugusto já tentei, porém mesmo assim o form é enviado.

Comment: Qual a melhor forma para verificar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código abaixo pode resolver o seu problema.

```
$('#FornecedorNovo').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Coloca o preventDefault no início da função

    var url  = "/Fornecedor/VerificaInscricao";
    var Insc = $("#InscricaoEstadual").val();
    var form = this,
       $form = $(form); // Salvamos o formulário atual em uma variável

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { insc: Insc },
        datatype: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.resultado == true) {
                alert('Já existe esta inscrição estadual cadastrada para outro fornecedor.');
            } else {
                $form.off('submit').submit();
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: eu preciso chamar outra `function` logo abaixo, passando outra `url` e caso seja `true` também não poderá enviar o `form`, será que não dá problemas?

Comment: Eu tentei assim chamando a function no `else` e me retorna erro. Porque será que está retornando ?

Comment: Mariana tenta fazer um debug passo a passo.